# Running with some issues with IIS deployment for a py framework using "httpPlatformHandler"

Tags: python, iis, httphandler, fastapiusers

The IIS is running good when presented with a standard web.config and the IIS list's out the index page with the items on the folder/dir unless mimed to render on browsers.

The issue comes with the web.config as shared by Microsoft on their learn portal to deploy the framework with arguments.

As and when the web.config as per the learn portal is added and replaced with the working web.config (Will diff the config later) the IIS Authentication is pending. Actually all the Web-modules are raising error but with no exception rather a nimicking pointer ref id:  0x8007000d

Looks like my web.config is not aligned with the IIS sub-modules and they error with the web.config address.

The localhost:80 is working fine with the default IIS page out.
The custom localhost:8080 is with the attached error page.

I am trying to get the py framework running with the standard IIS and get the routes as on browsers address bar to be minimal.

Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows

[image: ISE Error]

[image: Config Editor]

Comment: That page is known to be broken. Read mine instead, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Its the IIS who is misbehaving, the solution of yours with waitress as reload or debug is a read there. Any help with the deployment of FAPI with the IIS will be appreciated, thanks Li

Comment: Literally there is no difficulty to get your Django/Flask/FastAPI web app running on waitress. Then follow my blog post to forward traffic from IIS to waitress. IIS won't misbehave if you use the right settings, and like I said you won't find from the article you referred to.

Comment: Thanks, Li, for the reload of FAPI and waitress, there is a issue with my setup I am unable to create a script handler and call the python exec as in web.config to do a port forward as cgi, chao

Comment: You can also use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.